# Missing recommended icon file - iOS App / PhoneGap Build

Tags: cordova, phonegap-build

Following error started prompting in front of me when I tried to submit my [phonegap](https://build.phonegap.com) built iOS App (.ipa) to the App Store using xCode.

1. **Missing recommended icon file** - The bundle does not contain an app icon for iPhone / iPod Touch of exactly '120x120' pixels, in .png format.
2. **Missing recommended icon file** - The bundle does not contain an app icon for iPad of exactly '76x76' pixels, in .png format.
3. **Missing recommended icon file** - The bundle does not contain an app icon for iPad of exactly '152x152' pixels, in .png format.

Now the problem is that the these icons are present in my source directory and are configured properly. But still i'm getting this error again and again. Any kind of help would be much appreciated.

Comment: which CLI version did you use to compile the app?

Comment: I'm using https://build.phonegap.com for building.

Comment: Yes, and you can configure the CLI to use. If you don't set any, I think it will use 5.2.0. Try setting it to 6.0.0.

Comment: I'm also getting same error and tried the accepted solution but not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have managed to figure it out by myself. I have used an [online icon generator tool](http://pgicons.abiro.com). Later on I came to know that the images have the correct names but the sizes were different. I just re-sized the images and it worked perfectly.

Cheers!

Comment: Hi Imran, I have used the same link to generate icons and replace my icon folder with their icons. But error remains idle

Answer (score 1):

What framework are you using? If you're using Ionic I recommend using the Resources generator for icons and splash screens: http://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/icon-splashscreen.html

If not - just redo everything again. It's the equivalent of turning the computer on and off. Failing that the Phonegap Build help forums have some solutions/suggestions.

Comment: I'm simply using jQuery Mobile and have put all of my icons and screens inside the 'res' directory in root. I have used the following online resource to generate these icons http://pgicons.abiro.com.

Comment: Interesting. I've never seen that generator. I stopped using phonegap build when I moved to Ionic. I used to use jQM too. In that case I suggest trying the PGB forums - there will be people who've used this resource.

Comment: Thanks for your time and help!